# What are all the 7 camos I need to unlock diamond on a ASM1

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I'm not sure what camos I need to unlock because there are about 15 camos in total and it says I only need 7. Which are those 7?

Answer (score -1):

Go to:

- Operator
- Challenges
- Weapons
- Whatever category (Assault, etc)
- Click on the gun
- It lists the Camos you need